# Timer Object wont animate images

Tags: java, animation, timer

I a using a timer to change the icon in a JLabel every second.
I initialised  and started the timer in the GUI constructor:

```
images[0] =new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("connected.png"));
        images[1] =new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("notConnected.png"));
        imageAnimator = new Timer(1000, animateImages());
        imageAnimator.start();
```

And wrapped the method the timer calls in a swingWorker thread:

```
private ActionListener animateImages() {

        System.out.println("in animateIMages method");
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    System.out.println("In swingworker ");
                    if (currentImage==0) {
                        currentImage=1;
                        connectionStatusLabel.setIcon(images[currentImage]);
                        System.out.println("in if currentImage==0: currentIMage should now be 1: "+ currentImage);
                    }
                    else {
                        currentImage=0;
                        connectionStatusLabel.setIcon(images[currentImage]);
                        System.out.println("in if else: currentIMage should now be 0: "+ currentImage);
                    }//end else
                    return null;
                }

            };//end worker thread
```

However the image only changes once where the first if statement is executed.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And wrapped the method the timer calls in a swingWorker thread:

You don't want to do that. All updates to a GUI should be done in the EDT. The code in the SwingWorker executes in a separate Thread, which is NOT what you want.

The only time you might use a SwingWorker for this would be if you are reading the image from disk. Then the worker code would read the image and then publish() the result. In your case is looks like the Icon is already in memory so there is no need for the SwingWorker.

Just use the Timer and swap the Icon in the ActionListener directly.

Comment: Thanks. Removed the Swing worker thread but same result. It seems ActionListener method is only called once by the Timer, not every second....

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
Used a annonmonous ActionListner inner class in the Timer constructor and worked fine:

```
imageAnimator = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //change images here
```

Thanks for input.
C